# Select Entry when multiple products and multiple activation dates exist

Tags: oracle

I am using SQL Service and have not been able to figure out this code. I have a table that looks like this:

```
Name1   ID1 PG1 7/15/2014   PN1 SG1
Name1   ID1 PG1 7/17/2014   PN1 SG1
Name1   ID1 PG1 7/18/2014   PN1 SG1
Name1   ID1 PG1 7/15/2014   PN2 SG1
Name1   ID1 PG1 7/15/2014   PN3 SG1
Name2   ID2 PG1 7/25/2014   PN1 SG2
```

Here PG is a product group and PN is a product number and SG is a service group.

The issue I have is some people activate and the deactivate products like PN1 numerous times within a month.

I want my results to look like this

```
Name1   ID1 PG1 7/15/2014   PN1 SG1
Name1   ID1 PG1 7/15/2014   PN2 SG1
Name1   ID1 PG1 7/15/2014   PN3 SG1
Name2   ID2 PG1 7/25/2014   PN1 SG2
```

where I have the first date they activated a specific product.

What I have so far is

```
Select name, ID, PG, min(distinct(Date)), PN, SG
From Sales_Table
Group By Name, ID, PG, PN
```

I can't get the grouping to work.

Comment: Are you not getting the result you want, or are you getting an error you don't understand? Your example has at least two errors but not sure if that's what you're actually running. (You don't have SG in the group-by clause; and the distinct shouldn't be there). Other than that it looks like it should give you what you want... so can you clarify your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query. I used the column name as `DT` for the Date column, because DATE is a reserved word in Oracle.

```
SELECT
    st.*
FROM SALES_TABLE st
INNER JOIN
(   
    SELECT
        PG,
        PN,
        SG,
        MIN(DT) min_dt
    FROM SALES_TABLE
) minimum_date
ON st.PG = minimum_date.PG AND st.PN = minimum_date.PN AND st.SG = minimum_date.SG AND st.DT = minimum_date.min_dt;
```

Basically, you select the minimum date for a combination of `PG`, `PN`, and `SG`. Then, you select the rows from the `SALES_TABLE` with the minimum date value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the `row_number()` function:

```
Select name, ID, PG, date, PN, SG
From (select st.*, row_number() over (partition by id, pn date desc) as seqnum
      from Sales_Table st
     ) st
where seqnum = 1;
```

`date` is a reserved word in Oracle.  It is a good idea to avoid reserved words for column and table names.